Comet Lake PCH-LP cAVS dummy output
hi im new to ubuntu so i kinda need help
heres my neofetch output
enter image description here
also my probe
https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=2f53f6286d

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
